# Strange warning for ValidationError in Pydantic V2

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I updated my FastAPI to `Pydantic 2.5.2` and I suddenly get the following warning in the logs.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/_migration.py:283: UserWarning: `pydantic.error_wrappers:ValidationError` has been moved to `pydantic:ValidationError`.
warnings.warn(f'`{import_path}` has been moved to `{new_location}`.')
```

Is that problematic and do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use from `from pydantic import ValidationError` instead of `from pydantic.error_wrappers import ValidationError`.

Now your code works correctly and it's just warning, but in the future versions of Pydantic it will cause the import error.

If you don't import `ValidationError` in your code, it probably does one of the libraries you use. In this case just ignore this warning.

Comment: Many thanks for your input. As you say, it must be some library. How can I suppress such a kind of warning?